# How to copy an array to another Document in MongoDB using Java?

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, binary-tree, transitive-closure-table

In MongoDB and Java, I am building a binary tree using closure table concept. Say my initial data is as below:

```
{
   "userid" : "1", "parent" : "root", "position" : "",
   "ancestry": ["1"]
}
# ...
{
   "userid" : "7", "parent" : "5", "position" : "right",
   "ancestry": ["1", "5", "7"]
}
{
   "userid" : "10", "parent" : "7", "position" : "right",
   "ancestry": []
}
```

When inserting new user, I want to set its ancestry by:
- get parent ancestry
- insert to child ancestry
- then add child userid (this is no issue using addToSet after)

For user 3, result will be:

```
"ancestry": ["1", "5", "7", "10"]
```

How do I elegantly get the array from the parent, copy it to the child?
I am using MongoDB Java Driver 3.x, kindly help.

Thank you before.

Comment: Please add anything you have tried so far

Comment: @SagarReddy To be frank, haven't found any reference to do this. Most references are to get array and iterate through them. No "shortcut" get the entire array and, say, 'updateOne'?

Comment: Take  a look at DBRef. See if it helps you

Comment: @SagarReddy Thank you, will do then update results